# Relationship between Cohomology groups/rings related to a topological group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, topological-groups, group-cohomology

I have recently learnt about group cohomology and I was curious what is the relationship between the different cohomology groups which we can associate to a give topological group $G$. I thought of three different cohomology groups related to $G$:

- group cohomology $H_{grp}^*(G; M)$
- cohomology $H^*(BG; M)$ of the $BG$
- cohomology $H^*(G; M)$ of $G$ as a topological space

How are these related? I have posed my question in terms of groups but I am also interested in the same question in terms of cohomology rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering $G=S^1,$ so that $BG$ is the infinite-dimensional complex projective space, you can see immediately that there’s no easy relationship between your second two cohomologies. There is actually an excellent relationship here, but it’s in homotopy: the homotopy groups of $BG$ are exactly those of $G,$ shifted up one level. The group cohomology of $G,$ in terms of the standard definition you’ve presumably just learned, is the topological cohomology of the classifying space of the *discrete* group underlying $G.$ In general, this will be some completely different and uninteresting thing, since it totally ignores the topology on $G$, although there are some particular cases where you want it.

Comment: I know of the discrete case but I am specifically interested in the topological group case. The group cohomology I have recently learnt uses the normalised chain complexes. These are sets of functions $f\colon G^n \to M$ which are equal to zero whenever one of the entries in $f$ is the identity of $G$ and $M$ is a $G$-module.

Comment: @joe Yes, that is the cohomology of the underlying discrete group. It doesn't use the topology.

Comment: @KevinArlin are you saying that group cohomology is "uninteresting?" I think that's a misleading comment.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I just meant that if you're interested in a topological group $G$, most often the group cohomology of the underlying discrete group is not interesting to you. I've also never found people to work much on the cohomology of infinite discrete groups at all, and of course the typical topological groups are very much infinite.

Comment: @KevinArlin cohomology of infinite discrete groups is a very active and useful area of study, particularly things like SL(2,Z), Out(F_n), the mapping class groups of surfaces, etc.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Right, those aren't very infinite, though--maybe if I say "uncountable" we're converging.

Comment: I see thank you @KevinArlin!! @CheerfulParsnip what are some of the interesting infinite discrete groups? I know of Mapping class groups and Out(F_n) but what others are interesting?

Comment: @joe the field of geometric group theory studies a whole class of interesting discrete groups, often by finding nice spaces that the groups act on.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I see, thank you!!